# Collect incremental results from Tornado's ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tornado, blinker

I have a `tornado` application which needs to run a blocking function on `ProcessPoolExecutor`. This blocking function employs a library which emits incremental results via `blinker` events. I'd like to collect these events and send them back to my `tornado` app as they occur.

At first, `tornado` seemed ideal for this use case because its asynchronous. I thought I could simply pass a `tornado.queues.Queue` object to the function to be run on the pool and then `put()` events onto this queue as part of my `blinker` event callback.

However, reading the docs of `tornado.queues.Queue`, I learned they are not managed across processes like `multiprocessing.Queue` and are not thread safe.

Is there a way to retrieve these events from the `pool` as they occur? Should I wrap `multiprocessing.Queue` so it produces `Futures`? That seems unlikely to work as I doubt the internals of `multiprocessing` are compatible with `tornado`.

[EDIT]
There are some good clues here: https://gist.github.com/hoffrocket/8050711

Answer (score 1):

To collect anything but the return value of a task passed to a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, you must use a `multiprocessing.Queue` (or other object from the `multiprocessing` library). Then, since `multiprocessing.Queue` only exposes a synchronous interface, you must use another thread in the parent process to read from the queue (without reaching into implementation details. There's a file descriptor that could be used here, but we'll ignore that for now since it's undocumented and subject to change).

Here's a quick untested example:

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
proc_pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
thread_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

async def read_events():
    while True:
        event = await thread_pool.submit(queue.get)
        print(event)

async def foo():
    IOLoop.current.spawn_callback(read_events)
    await proc_pool.submit(do_something_and_write_to_queue)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is more or less what I ended up doing, but used the `aioprocessing` module which supports a non-blocking `AioQueue.coro_get`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simply than that. Here's a coroutine that submits four slow function calls to subprocesses and awaits them:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

from tornado import gen, ioloop

pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()


def calculate_slowly(x):
    sleep(x)
    return x


async def parallel_tasks():
    # Create futures in a randomized order.
    futures = [gen.convert_yielded(pool.submit(calculate_slowly, i))
               for i in [1, 3, 2, 4]]

    wait_iterator = gen.WaitIterator(*futures)
    while not wait_iterator.done():
        try:
            result = await wait_iterator.next()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error {} from {}".format(e, wait_iterator.current_future))
        else:
            print("Result {} received from future number {}".format(
                result, wait_iterator.current_index))


ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(parallel_tasks)
```

It outputs:

```
Result 1 received from future number 0
Result 2 received from future number 2
Result 3 received from future number 1
Result 4 received from future number 3
```

You can see that the coroutine receives results in the order they complete, not the order they were submitted: future number 1 resolves after future number 2, because future number 1 slept longer. convert_yielded transforms the Futures returned by ProcessPoolExecutor into Tornado-compatible Futures that can be awaited in a coroutine.

Each future resolves to the value returned by calculate_slowly: in this case it's the same number that was passed into calculate_slowly, and the same number of seconds as calculate_slowly sleeps.

To include this in a RequestHandler, try something like this:

```
class MainHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        self.write("Starting....\n")
        self.flush()

        futures = [gen.convert_yielded(pool.submit(calculate_slowly, i))
                   for i in [1, 3, 2, 4]]

        wait_iterator = gen.WaitIterator(*futures)
        while not wait_iterator.done():
            result = await wait_iterator.next()
            self.write("Result {} received from future number {}\n".format(
                result, wait_iterator.current_index))

            self.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

You can observe if you `curl localhost:8888` that the server responds incrementally to the client request.

Comment: That's not quite what I mean. To clarify, I have a single slow function call. And, that function call emits a number of events via `blinker`. I'd like to collect those events and send them back to the main tornado thread. I believe the code you have here runs four slow functions in parallel, rather than one slow function.